# Jframe window will not work anymore

Tags: java

```
package Jframe;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaWindows {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame Window = new JFrame();
        JLabel Label = new JLabel("test");
        JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Heart.png");
        Window.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        Window.add(Panel);
        Window.add(Label);
        Window.setSize(500,750);
        Panel.setSize(500, 900);
        Window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
        Window.pack();
    }
}
```

About 10 min ago this code worked. It made a window that was about 100,100 with a 500,900 panel that was sized correctly. The window was not 500,750 like i specified I don't know what went wrong there but all sudden the window wont run in Eclipse. I deleted window.pack(); and retyped it now its broke. Any ideas?

Comment: `window.setVisible(true);`...

Comment: @Reimeus Thank you i feel stupid now. Also why isn't "Window" sized to 500,750?

Comment: From the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html): "JFrame [constructor] Constructs a new frame that is initially invisible."  You need to call [window.setVisible(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).  ALSO: your variables should start with lower-case: "window", "panel", etc.

Comment: "Window" is not 500x750 because you called pack(), which discards any existing size and determines its size by recursively asking its children what size they want to be, and then sets its own size to accommodate that.

Comment: @FredK Thank you I understood that answer sorry for the easy questions just starting out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set visibility of the frame

```
window.setVisible(true);
```